# Insert a line before specific ID and renumerate ID column

Tags: linux, sed, awk

A file contains ID, Name and other columns. I want to insert a row containing name with details before a specific ID. Then ID column should be updated with proper ID sequence.

**Example**

Sample File content:

```
Header1
Header2
1 AAA ...
2 BBB ...
3 CCC ...
4 XXX ...
5 YYY ...
6 ZZZ ...
Footer
```

I want to insert `MMM ...` before ID #4 i.e. before a row `4 XXX ...`

Desired output:

```
Header1
Header2
1 AAA ...
2 BBB ...
3 CCC ...
4 MMM ...
5 XXX ...
6 YYY ...
7 ZZZ ...
Footer
```

I could do proper insert using following command but not sure how to update ID column with proper numbering.

```
sed '/^\s*4/ i 4 MMM ...' file
```

It would be appreciable if you could help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option can be:

```
awk '/^4/ {print ++i, "MMM"} /^[0-9]/ {$1=++i} 1' file
```

#### Explanation

- `/^4/ {print ++i, "MMM"}` on line starting with `4`, print `MMM` with an incremental value.
- `/^[0-9]/ {$1=++i}` on lines starting with number, set first field to an incremental value.
- `1` print line

#### Test

```
$ awk '/^4/ {print ++i, "MMM"} /^[0-9]/ {$1=++i} 1' file
Header1
Header2
1 AAA ...
2 BBB ...
3 CCC ...
4 MMM
5 XXX ...
6 YYY ...
7 ZZZ ...
Footer
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution with explanation! that works very well... Would wait to see any other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/^4 /{print "4 MMM ..."; inc=1} /^[[:digit:]]/{$1+=inc} 1' file
Header1
Header2
1 AAA ...
2 BBB ...
3 CCC ...
4 MMM ...
5 XXX ...
6 YYY ...
7 ZZZ ...
Footer
```